# how do i do Server Side Rendering NextJs?

Tags: next.js

In a Next.js application, you want to implement client-side routing for a specific route, but you also need to fetch data from an API when the page loads. How would you achieve this dual functionality? Explain the steps and any relevant Next.js features or components you would use.

client-side routing and data fetching in a Next.js application

Comment: Please read  the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) and  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). Just copy/pasting your assignments will not win you any friends.

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward. Per [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-fetch):

> You can use fetch with async/await in Server Components, in Route
> Handlers, and in Server Actions.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> async function getData() {
>   const res = await fetch('https://api.example.com/...')
>   // The return value is *not* serialized
>   // You can return Date, Map, Set, etc.
>  
>   if (!res.ok) {
>     // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
>     throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
>   }
>  
>   return res.json()
> }
>  
> export default async function Page() {
>   const data = await getData()
>  
>   return <main></main>
> }
> ```